# Find the correlation coefficient of Y^2 and Z^2

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables and $X_i\sim N(\beta +  \gamma z_i,\sigma^2)$, here $\sum_{i=1}^nz_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nz_i^2 = 1$.

Now let $Y:= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $Z:= \sum_{i=1}^n z_iX_i$ and find the correlation coefficient of $Y^2$ and $Z^2$.

I calculated this by expanding $E[Y^2Z^2]$ and it really took me a long time.Is there any way to calculate the correlation coefficient without calculating $E[Y^2Z^2]$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I centralized $X_i$ and it is a little easier.

Comment: What does $N(\beta+\gamma z_i)$ mean? Do you mean $N(\beta,\gamma z_i)$?

Comment: I don't understand what the variances are. $z_i$'s are not all positive and you cannot have negative variance.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The variance is $\sigma^2$. Sorry for the typo, I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is handsome here to standardize and work with rv's with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

Any rv $X$ that has a variance can be written as $\sigma_X U+\mu_X$.

Further I would go straight for covariance and correlation.

Let $U=\sum_{i=1}^nr_iW_i$ and $V=\sum_{i=1}^ns_iW_i$.

Then by bilinearity of covariance:$$\mathsf{Cov}\left(U^{2},V^{2}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i'=1}^{n}\sum_{j'=1}^{n}r_{i}s_{j}r_{i'}s_{j'}\mathsf{Cov}\left(W_{i}W_{j},W_{i'}W_{j'}\right)$$

Then several cases must be discerned and by independence quite some terms fall away.

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah I also tried doing with mean 0 and I think it's better than doing with different means.

Comment: Yep, and it is handsome to know that the correlation of rv's  $X$ and $Y$ is just $\mathbb EUV$ if $U,V$ are the standardizations of $X$ and $Y$.